# how to fetch data between two dates in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, between

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

how to fetch record between two dates in sql server 2008. 
       im using I-batis query

eg.

```
 select * from T_SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION WHERE status='PEND' and from_date_time >='2013-01-09 04:16:52.0' AND to_date_time<='2013-01-09 04:16:52.0'
```

where two columns are in datetime format in Sql server 2008

Answer (score 3):

You could use SQL 2005's *BETWEEN* operator i.e.

```
WHERE createdate BETWEEN '01-01-01 21:20:32.71' AND '10-01-01 21:20:32.71'
```

**Edit: If you want to fetch data between two different fields you should be able to do the following**

```
WHERE createdate >= from_date AND createdate < to_date
```

Let me know how it works!

Comment: Thanks Bill. One more query.Suppose if im selecting from two columns.what i have to change.(say for From _date column and To_date column)

Comment: [Using between to check datetime values is perhaps not the best idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153837/datediff-or-between-for-date-ranges-in-sql-queries/14153977#comment19604719_14153977)