# Selecting records between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Ive column CREATEDDATE ( DATETIME ) I need to find all rows between two dates
$startDate $endDate format ('d/m/Y') ?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
 WHERE CREATEDDATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, $startDate, 103)
 AND CREATEDDATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, $endDate, 103)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0478/5 where is the problem ?!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: [what have you tried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)..??

Comment: +1 for good response and explaination..

Comment: I understant first close votes, but not the last, when question was updated and sqlfiddle was provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CREATEDDATE from table where CREATEDDATE BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2
```

or you can use

```
select CREATEDDATE from table where CREATEDDATE > $date1 AND CREATEDDATE < $date2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple and could be find by googling..
You should google first before asking question..

```
Select * From Tbl where CREATEDDATE between $date1 and  $date2
```

if $date1 is `varchar` then you have to use `CONVERT(DATETIME, $date1, 103)` (for 'd/m/y')

 For datetime convertion in sql you can refer [this link..](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Here is the Solution :

[updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0478/11)

Comment: sorry but it doesnt work ..

Comment: There is a rather lengthy comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14153977/569436) about the pitfalls of using between.

Comment: @Myaw "sorry but it doesnt work" is not very informative. Update your question with what is not working. BTW, dates does not have a format. Strings do but surely you are not having dates in a string data type?

Comment: I ve tried that too, still not working ... SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CREATEDDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, $startDate, 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, $endDate, 103)

Comment: what is the $startdate (in which format like dd/MM/yyyy or any other ... )???

Comment: More info on why you should never use BETWEEN for date range queries: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: $startDate/$endDate format d/m/Y

Comment: Also with SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CREATEDDATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, $startDate, 103) AND CREATEDDATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, $endDate, 103) still not working

Comment: WHAT DOES "not working" MEAN?

Comment: CREATEDDATE DATETIME Im using convert(datetime,,103) when storing date in the CREATEDDATE column

Comment: SO, The query retour no data but in my table I've data stored between the both date

Comment: please create a new SQL Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) with test data and query.. some time there may be issue with time (hour, minute, sec,...)

Comment: Hum, First time using sqlfiddle so I don't know how it work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a80d/2

Comment: @Myaw somthing like [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d22a4/1)? You are using datetime. No need to add format when saving. If you want a specific format when presenting the dates you should do that in the client.

Comment: Yep Mekael, you have used maybe iso format but I'm using format dd/mm/YY what the client have choosed as date

Comment: @ Sac , still no data retourned :s

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0478/9 why this query retourn no data?

Comment: try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d22a4/6

Comment: @Myaw because you are converting a datetime to a string that is then converted back to a datetime again. Convert from string to datetime when assigning your variables. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0478/6

Comment: its working know thanks a lot guys, But why the @toDate is not Included ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0478/11

Comment: just using DATEADD(d,1,@toDate) and now its work...

Comment: @Myaw, Explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15342169/842935) why returns no data.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue in sqlfiddle is that you are casting string to date in variable declaration but sql sentence:

```
declare @FromDate datetime = '11/03/2013'  --here a type casting!!
declare @ToDate datetime = '12/03/2013'
```

Then this has no effect:

```
xCreatedDate < convert(datetime,@ToDate,103)  --@toDate is yet a date!!
```

To fix, change datetime to date in variable declaration:

```
declare @FromDate varchar(10) = '11/03/2013'  --here without casting!!
declare @ToDate varchar(10) = '12/03/2013'
```