# Sql Server where clause between two dates not gives expected output

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

This is my simple query to fetch dates using 'between' operator.

```
create table dummy (mydate datetime);
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-20 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-21 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-22 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-23 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-24 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-25 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-26 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-27 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-28 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-29 10:30:00.000');
 insert into dummy values('2013-03-30 10:30:00.000');
```

The qiuery I m using is: 
`select * from dummy where mydate between ('3/01/2013 12:00:00 AM') and ('3/30/2013 12:00:00 AM')`

Here  `2013-03-30 10:30:00.000` , should also be returned.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7026/1)

Comment: Use the same (unambiguous) datetime format as your insert statements use.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I cnt change the insertion format `2013-03-30 10:30:00.000`, but yes in select query i can do changes

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about. The format in the insert is correct for all language/dateformat settings.

Comment: @MartinSmith - except that when it uses a space rather than `T`, it's still ambiguous. `2013-03-30T10:30:00` is unambiguous. If you run `set language british; select MONTH('2013-03-04 10:30:00')` you'll get `4` as a result.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Just was editing an example into my previous comment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `set language british; select MONTH('2013-03-04 10:30:00.000')` returns `3`

Comment: @MartinSmith - ah - it's a difference of versions. On 2005 and earlier, it returns 4. On 2008 and later it returns 3. So I still wouldn't recommend it as an "unambiguous" format.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes you're right `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` is the unambiguous one. http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp

Comment: @MartinSmith From SQL Server 2008 the string literal passed to `month` is treated as a `datetime2` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14271)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the datetime format in your where clause and check the values with `>=` and `<` instead.

```
select * 
from dummy 
where mydate >= '20130301' and
      mydate < '20130401'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, just want to know is their any difference using `>=`  or `between` operator.

Comment: @Satindersingh Yes there is a big difference. `between` is inclusive. [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: here you have used 4 month, and am using my enddate as 30 for 3 month. If adding one day will solve then it can be done with my existing query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7026/19

Comment: #ERROR!

Comment: @Satindersingh then it will include values from the next day and I don't think you want that. You should read the article I linked to in the earlier comment.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Thank you verymuch, now onwards i will never use `BETWEEN` for `Datetime` datatype

Answer (score 3):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7026/4)**

```
select * 
from dummy 
where mydate between ('3/01/2013 12:00:00') 
and ('3/30/2013 12:00:00')
```

Result:

```
|                       MYDATE |
--------------------------------
| March, 20 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 21 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 22 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 23 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 24 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 25 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 26 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 27 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 28 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 29 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
| March, 30 2013 10:30:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume(my culture has no `AM/PM` designator) that the `12 AM` means midnight(so from 29th to 30th). So either use `12 PM` or omit the `AM/PM` designator.

```
mydate between ('3/01/2013 12:00:00 AM') 
and ('3/30/2013 12:00:00 PM')
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7026/3/0)

You could also remove the time part and add one day which means midnight:

```
mydate between '2013-03-01' and '2013-03-31'
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7026/11/0)

Comment: @Satindersingh: Have you seen my demos?

Comment: Thanks its wroking, So now have to pass date '2013-03-01' format from c#

Comment: Curiosity want to know, as per Mikael Eriksson answer , using `>=` is good in my case, or should i go with urs

Comment: @Satindersingh: That's a matter of taste, do what you find easier to read.

Comment: @Satindersingh I would say it is a bit more then a matter of taste. [Here is a rant of mine in a comment to another question that explains a bit about the trouble you can have with `between`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153837/datediff-or-between-for-date-ranges-in-sql-queries#comment19604719_14153977).

Answer (score 0):

Remember, date time data uses 24hour clock (00:00:00 to 23:59:59).
The mistake is in the 'AM' designation in the condition '3/30/2013 12:00:00 AM', because 12:00:00 AM is equal to 00:00:00, and 10:30:00 is "Greater than" 12:00:00 AM, that's why the value '2013-03-30 10:30:00.000' it's not in the selected values.

Use
    select *
    from dummy
    where mydate between
    ('3/01/2013 12:00:00')
    and
    ('3/30/2013 12:00:00')