# How to get data according to timestamps in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table call viewed books like below in database

```
book_id     user_uniq_id   date
3           111111         2018-11-06 00:29:15
```

like that so many rows I need to get book_id and user_uniq_id according to date

as a example this date these users viewed these books like that

How can I write a sql query for this in codeigniter

Comment: Your question isn't clear... Could you try adding another example explaining wanted output and multiple input exemples?

Comment: you can use `beetween`
[maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731376/sql-server-where-clause-between-two-dates-not-gives-expected-output)

Comment: its clear but need enough details in the answer. it's not specific.

Comment: `$results = $this->db->order_by('date' 'DESC')->get('viewed_books')->result();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is clear enough, but from what i got you want a query based on the timestamp then you should try this.

```
$timestamp = '2018-11-06 00:29:15';

$this->db->select('book_id, user_uniq_id');

$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('date' => '>' . $timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT book_id, user_uniq_id from viewed_books ORDER BY date";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$bookData= $query->result_array();
```

You can see your results from

```
var_dump($bookData);
```

Hope this is the answer you seek